# Forcing screen-reader read alt-text on a text element when creating a PDF in iText7

Tags: pdf, itext, screen-readers, itext7

Is there any way to add alt text to a text element in iText? I have seen there is a way to do it for images. Basically, I would like the screen reader to read something besides the actual text that is being displayed. There are two situations in my document that I would need to do this.

One is when the screen-reader is reading an acronym I would like the alt-text to force the screen reader to read each letter instead of trying to read a word. (ie read DIET as D-I-E-T instead of diet)

The second is when it is reading a phone number I would like it to read outloud "phone" before the number. In the document it is currently just the number which would be a little confusing for disabled users. I am unable to actually change the layout to include the word "phone" for non-technical reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method for that.

```
new Paragraph("Lorem").getAccessibilityProperties().setActualText("Ipsum")
```

You can call this method on every class that implements `IAccessibleElement`.

Comment: I have tried implementing this. When I look at the tag's properties in Adobe Acrobat the "Actual text" will read as what I set in iText, (say setting it to "Fox" just to test) however the screen-reader will simply read whatever text is there.

Comment: Try copy-pasting the text that is there. That should give an idea of what is happening. It should at least give you the ActualText.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, do you mean copy-pasting the text that is in the generated PDF? So, when I copy the text from the PDF and paste it, it should paste the actual text rather than the text that is shown?

Comment: Yes, when you copy-paste the text from the PDF to something like notepad, it should give you the ActualText.

Comment: Yes, something must be wrong because this is not happening for me. I have been using the exact method you defined and yet it is still copy-pasting the text being displayed. Any idea what could be wrong? It is a tagged document if that is important.

Comment: I'm currently not in the office.
There are alternate accessibility properties you can set. I think there's even a property to help read-aloud features. I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: I have currently tried setAlternateDescription, setExpansion, and setActualText just fyi. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165095/discussion-between-joris-schellekens-and-scott13).